# SQL Server: How to get rows where the date is older than X years?

Tags: sql, sql-server

### Question

I would like to pull all assets from a database which is a certain amount of years old. Is this statement correct?

### Background

The database is called `AssetRegister`

The table is called `dbo.Assets`

the column is called `AcquiredDate`

### Statement so far

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Assets WHERE AcquiredDate < '2008-01-01'
```

Comment: And where is the problem? SQL query seems to be okay.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Assets                  
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, AcquiredDate, GetDate()) >= 8
```

For an performance optimized query look at [@Horaciuxs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26993036/575376).

Comment: Received this error message: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'curdate' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: I see you use SQL-Server instead of MySQL. I updated my answer and removeed the wrong tag from your question.

Comment: Thank you, however i am still recieving an error message: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: SELECT * FROM dbo.Assets                  
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, AcquiredDate, GetDate()) = 8 - use this query. He missed ).

Comment: ok this query brings back 0 records? The one I create brings back 4? What is the difference between the two?

Comment: @DanCundy: Because you grab also records older than 8 years. I changed it to `>=` instead of `=`. You really need to be specific in your question.

Comment: CAREFUL - DATEDIFF only looks at calendar year, if you are deleting records on this basis you could delete data 9 years & 1 day old.....

Comment: @SinisterPenguin: No idea what you mean. Did you read the question?

Comment: @juergen-d I've gone a little off topic - I've tried to clarify in an answer below but I think it's a point worth making about a query not always doing quite what you may think it is doing.

Answer (score 13):

The answer by @Juergen bring the right results:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Assets                  
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, AcquiredDate, GetDate()) >= 8
```

But, the SQL optimizer can't use an index on AcquiredDate, even if one exists. It will literally have to evaluate this function for every row of the table.

For big tables is recommended to use:

```
DECLARE @limitDate Date
SELECT @limitDate=DATEADD(year,-8,GETDATE()) --Calculate limit date 8 year before now.

SELECT * FROM dbo.Assets                  
WHERE AcquiredDate <= @limitDate
```

Or simply:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Assets                  
    WHERE AcquiredDate <= DATEADD(year,-8,GETDATE())
```

Comment: @DanCundy have you look at this?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Assets WHERE AcquiredDate >= '2006-01-01'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Assets WHERE AcquiredDate >= (year(getdate()) - 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

CAREFUL - DATEDIFF only looks at year. Consider this query:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year,'2012-10-01','2022-06-01')
```

clearly the date is 9 years 8 months old but the query returns 10. So if you are deleting records >= 10 years old based on this kind of query you're in a fix....

[image]

Better to use something like this as highlighted by @Horaciux

```
WHERE dt > DATEADD(YEAR,-10,'20220501')
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Assets 
 WHERE YEAR(AcquiredDate) < 2008
```

The solution posted by juergen d and Ankit are better, but if you want to compare the Year, you can use the YEAR function.