# how can I exclude rows if row exist within 2 hours?

Tags: mysql

| name | field1 | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | aerg | 2021:07:20 10:01:00 |
| aaa | aerg | 2021:07:20 10:07:00 |
| aaa | aerg | 2021:07:20 10:21:00 |
| aaa | aerg | 2021:07:20 12:11:00 |
| aaa | aerg | 2021:07:20 17:11:00 |
| bbb | grae | 2021:07:20 10:21:00 |
| ccc | aegg | 2021:07:20 10:21:00 |

if I have above data, how can I exclude rows if row exist within 2 hours? 
I would like to exclude data like below. (I don't need to display all names)

ex)

| name | field1 | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | aerg | 2021:07:20 10:01:00 |
| aaa | aerg | 2021:07:20 12:11:00 |
| aaa | aerg | 2021:07:20 17:11:00 |

Comment: do you mean exclude from select ?

Comment: nope.. I just want query a person data. I want exclude data if a data already exist within 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to filter out last 2 hours records from select result
- So you will need to have special condition in where clause.
- something like this `DATE_ADD(GETDATE(), INTERVAL -2 HOUR)`
- Refer here for more [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990053/sql-server-how-to-get-rows-where-the-date-is-older-than-x-years/26993036#26993036)

Answer (score 0):

isn't field1 important to you?
if the aaa user had another field1 value at 2021: 07: 20 10: 21: 00, wouldn't it make a difference in your output results?